# ComponentDidUpdate throwing Cannot read property props nextProps.Value of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the styling of a `<div>` tag of my component based when data gets updated in the parent component. More specifically, it's a list of `<div>`: when one element of this list is `onHover`, I try to trigger other images to `visibility: "hidden"`. Here's what I have so far (I've commented so that it helps in clarity):

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
  // if a componnent has been hovevered
  if (nextProps.isSelectedMouseEnterThumbnail) {
    // trigger the function to updated the div located within this component
    return this.updateOnHoverImage(nextProps, prevState)
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

updateOnHoverImage = (nextProps, prevState) => {

  let componentIndex = this.props.index;
  let onHoverComponentIndex = nextProps.selectedMouseEnterIndex;

  // for each component, it displays:
  // componentIndex: its index
  // onHoverComponentIndex: the index of the hovered component;
  // it does not start with null or undefined;

  console.log(componentIndex, onHoverComponentIndex);


  // if both matches, then trigger {visibility: "visible"}
  if (onHoverComponentIndex === componentIndex) {
    console.log(`visible for: ${componentIndex}`);
    return {
      visibility: "visible"
    }
    // Otherwise, trigger {visibility: "hidden"}
  } else if (onHoverComponentIndex !== componentIndex) {
    console.log(`hidden for: ${componentIndex}`);
    return {
      visibility: "hidden"
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Then, in my parent component:

```
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       counter: 0,
       selectedSection: "all",
       mock_data: mock_data,
       dataOnView: null,
       sections: ["all", "film", "music", "commercial"],
       selectedMouseEnterIndex: null,
       isSelectedMouseEnterThumbnail: false
     };
   };


 <IndexImageComponent
            onSelectedMouseEnterIndexImage={this.onSelectedMouseEnterIndexImage}
            onSelectedMouseLeaveIndexImage={this.onSelectedMouseLeaveIndexImage}
            index={index}
            ele={ele}
            {...this.state}
          />

   onSelectedMouseEnterIndexImage = (index) => {
     this.setState({
       selectedMouseEnterIndex: index,
       isSelectedMouseEnterThumbnail: true
     })
   };

   onSelectedMouseLeaveIndexImage = (index) => {
     this.setState({
       selectedMouseEnterIndex: null,
       isSelectedMouseEnterThumbnail: false
     })
   }
```

When I hover, the `console.log(visible for: ${componentIndex});` and `console.log(hidden for: ${componentIndex});` do work. But when I implement the style, such as this:

```
  <div
            style={this.updateOnHoverImage()}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.onSelectedMouseEnterIndexImage(index)}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.onSelectedMouseLeaveIndexImage(null)}
            className="index_image_component">
```

this errror happens: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedMouseEnterIndex' of undefined`.

Comment: `style={this.updateOnHoverImage()}` called without parameters.

Comment: if it is just for visible true or not, just store it to state and not return a function

Comment: But then if I replace my `return` with setState, I get the following: `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded`

Comment: Maybe a codesandbox would help

Comment: Have you tried using a variable instead of calling the function directly in `style` ?
ex: style={this.updatedStyle} and you update the value of this.updatedStyle when you hover.

I think the reason you get `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded` is because you call it multiple times when redering your `<div>`

Comment: @cyruslk I think i saw a comment of yours with a codesandbox but it is now deleted (?). Can you post it again?